# Wink detection on Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

There was a third-party app to snap pictures with winks: [winky on github](https://github.com/kaze0/winky). This app gets the eye gesture detection service using reflection and uses it to take pictures. But the service is unavailable since XE11.

Is there a way to detect winks in a Google Glass running on XE12? Glasses now support taking pictures with winks (which can be configured from settings), but is there any service available in GDK to detect winks? Or is there any event listener that fires when a wink is detected?

Comment: Does winky on github work on the new XE16 update?

Answer (score 5):

We're using the wink detector in one of the projects I'm working on. Our code is open source:

https://github.com/victorkp/DriveSafe4Glass

Comment: I may be missing something but it looks like the wink detection part of your code is just a stub that doesn't actually do anything.  Could you provide an example of using the wink detection feature please?

Comment: It is a stub that serves only to let the code compile. On Glass itself, that class and those methods are implemented. That code does work in DriveSafe.

Answer (score 1):

I can half-answer your question, there doesn't seem to be an official way to do it.

Looking at my Glass device, [this](https://cloudup.com/cZhaRo43vjK) seems to be the sensor that picks up on winking activity.

Looking through the GDK docs, I can't find any reference to this sensor or how to develop with it. This probably means that as of now, Google doesn't want you to detect winks on Glass.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed winky and it does not work on XE16. But I found this example which is really good and it works on XE16 too. The example: [EyeGestureDemo](http://github.com/thorikawa/GlassEyeGestureDemo)